# Confusion while Interpreting the Documentation - terminology <b>most</b> and <b>recent</b>

Tags: python

Answering a specific question, I stumbled upon while trying to interpret the Python Document

Referring to the documentation for [os.uname](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.uname) and  [os.unsetenv(varname)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.unsetenv) in  [os — Miscellaneous operating system interfaces](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#module-os), I wondered how to interpret

*Availability: **recent** flavors of Unix.*

*Availability: **most** flavors of Unix, Windows.*

How to determine what **recent** and **most** means. How do I know if my Python Script is supposed to work properly on a particular system I am targeting. Should I always rely on the fact

```
try
     <do something>
except <some-failure>:
     <fallback>
```

for example

```
try
    import os
    _uname = os.uname()
except AttributeError:
    import platform
    _uname = platform.uname()
```

Even when I know about the Unix Flavor and Version I am targeting?

Comment: These are the limitations of documentation. Unless you have someone dedicated to testing and updating the docs, this is what you end up with. This is not python specific, but unfortunately it is fairly universal. I hope you get an answer and we can add it to the docs, though - but 1 year from now it will be "recent flavors of Unix"

Comment: @DanHoerst: Yes you have some convincing argument. I am not being nitpick but rather trying to figure out what the general consensus is and what people are used to.

Comment: No I totally understand. I'm just addressing the issue of documentation, both open source and in general, as a whole. Unfortunately I don't see a solution yet as most contributors/developers want to actually develop and not write docs.

Comment: @downvoters: Please explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should always use the `try-except` form, simply because it will work everywhere the "unsafe" version works, and also potentially in places it does not.

For this particular Python function, however, you could use a little domain-specific knowledge to reason about where it would work. `os.uname` is based on the system call bearing the same name. From `man 2 uname`, we get the availability as being "SVr4, POSIX.1-2001", meaning that it will be available on any Linux distribution based on the 2001 version of the POSIX standard or later (or those coming from SVr4). That is, in effect, every Linux distribution you will encounter on a personal computer.

Comment: This is what my understanding as of now. I was just wondering if making the documents more specific would had been better. But when you write a cross platform script you would always end up thinking about alternatives as its always not possible to test across all platforms.